# Is there a way to record mouse movement and run it via python?

Tags: python, automation

I searched for the answer but nothing comes up. I want to make a script for the game, but i also want to make my mouse movement more unpredictable so i want to record my own mouse movement. Or record macro mouse movement in another program and run it via python maybe? How can i do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called `pyautogui` which you can download using the pip command in your terminal `pip install PyAutoGUI`

```
import pyautogui

a = pyautogui.position()

print(a)

>>> Point(x=1290, y=342)
```

you can run `pyautoqui.position()` anytime you want to get the mouse coordinates on the screen or create a loop which repeatedly gets the position of the mouse. In the loop below I added a `sleep(0.5)` so that it waits a small second jsut to show taht it works since without the sleep function it would run so fast I didn't have time to move my mouse and show that it worked.

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

for i in range(10):
    print(pyautogui.position())
    sleep(0.5)

>>>Point(x=689, y=540)
>>>Point(x=820, y=503)
>>>Point(x=1122, y=698)
>>>Point(x=528, y=608)
>>>Point(x=1316, y=301)
>>>Point(x=937, y=288)
>>>Point(x=734, y=529)
>>>Point(x=1055, y=310)
>>>Point(x=584, y=763)
>>>Point(x=740, y=298)
```

To move the mouse use:

```
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(100, 200)   # moves mouse to X of 100, Y of 200.
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(None, 500)  # moves mouse to X of 100, Y of 500.
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(600, None)  # moves mouse to X of 600, Y of 500.
```

Here `none` means to keep the `x or y` the same.

To move gradually over time use this:

```
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(100, 200, 2)   # moves mouse to X of 100, Y of 200 over 2 seconds
```

use `moveTo` to move to a coordinate, you can change `moveTo` to `move` and set the pixels to how many pixels you want to move from the current location.

Comment: Ok, so how to i put those coordinates in moveTo?

Comment: I edited the answer, check it out and if you need anything else you can search up pyautogui and go to their website. The library is quite useful and has many functions. https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html - cheat sheet